# Give buttons same behavior (twins)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I would like my UIButtons to interact with each other - (With the corresponding button)

First set of buttons;

```
@IBOutlet var P1button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P1button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P1button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P1button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P1button5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P1button6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P1button7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P1button8: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P1button9: UIButton!
```

Second set of buttons;

```
@IBOutlet var P2button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P2button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P2button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P2button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P2button5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P2button6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P2button7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P2button8: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var P2button9: UIButton!
```

In my code I apply an Image to **one** random P1button from an Array;

```
var buttons = [P1button1, P1button2, P1button3, P1button4, P1button5, P1button6, P1button7, P1button8, P1button9]
        buttons.shuffleInPlace()

        buttons[0].setImage(UIImage(named: "Green"), forState: .Normal)
```

Now, I want to know if there is a way to make the P2buttons "co-operate" with the P1buttons. Meaning that if an Image is applied to `P1button1`  then `P2button1` is set to the same image! (and so forth for all buttons)

Example;

```
P2button1.setImage = UIImage(P1button1)
```

This obviously doesn't work but hopefully gives you a clue about what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You... need a better data structure for this... 18 outlets is too much, almost no matter what you are doing...

Comment: right after buttons[0].setImage ... why don't you add P2button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "Green"), forState: .Normal)

Comment: @SamB Because buttons[0] could be any of the buttons from the Array. It's shuffled by the shuffleInPlace() function which means they will be in random order.

Comment: you need to assign tags to your buttons, then check if button[0] tag equals to P1Button tag and then you have all the info you need to assign the image ...See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802802/getting-at-a-uibutton-with-the-tag-property-iphone

Comment: Please don't do it with tags...

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be by subclassing `UIButton`.  Perhaps something like this...

```
class TwinButton {
    weak var twin: TwinButton?
}
```

Now, in your `viewDidLoad` method, link up all of the twins.

```
p1button1.twin = p2button1
p2button1.twin = p1button1
```

Now, I'd write a set of methods that have some "with twin" semantics...

```
extension TwinButton {
    setWithTwin(title: String)
    setWithTwin(backgroundImage: UIImage)
}
```

and those methods simply set the value on `self` and `twin`.